# How can I restrict a filter plugin to certain entity types?

Tags: 8

I have created a Filter Plugin which extends FilterBase and need to restrict it to certain entities, for example nodes and not comments.

How can I apply this condition?

I tried adding a context in the annotations, but it doesn't help.

```
/**
 * @Filter(
 *   id = "filter_ls",
 *   title = @Translation("Ls"),
 *   description = @Translation("Mark Ls"),
 *   type = Drupal\filter\Plugin\FilterInterface::TYPE_MARKUP_LANGUAGE,
 *   context = {
 *     "node" = @ContextDefinition("entity:node", label = @Translation("Node"), required = TRUE),
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

I also tried to see ContextAwarePluginTrait, but it needs the class to be abstract.

Comment: The node context is certainly not what you are looking for, the filter is configured in a text format and the text format is applied on the content of a formatted text field which then could be in any entity, not necessarily the global node in a node route.

Comment: @4k4 yes, I agree, so what can be the way out to filter based on node type or entity type ?

Comment: Normally a content editor can choose any text format he has access to. If you want to restrict this on a field configured in a content type or entity bundle then use the module https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats

Comment: As side note, Drupal core doesn't define any [`ContextAwarePluginTrait`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.9.x/search/ContextAwarePluginTrait) trait. There is [`ContextAwarePluginDefinitionTrait`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Plugin%21Definition%21ContextAwarePluginDefinitionTrait.php/trait/ContextAwarePluginDefinitionTrait/8.9.x), though, which doesn't require the class to be abstract.

Comment: (In fact, it is used from [`SectionStorageDefinition`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21layout_builder%21src%21SectionStorage%21SectionStorageDefinition.php/class/SectionStorageDefinition/8.9.x).)